Use of undeclared identifier 'BASELIB_API' react-native-unity
I'm getting these errors when I try to run my iOS project that uses react-native-unity. I followed all the steps mentioned in the ReadME and it works fine on android.

I'm using
   "@azesmway/react-native-unity": "^1.0.10",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.75.4"

and getting errors like:

MyApp/node_modules/@azesmway/react-native-unity/ios/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/external/baselib/Include/C/Baselib_Debug.h:17:1
Use of undeclared identifier 'BASELIB_API'


MyApp/node_modules/@azesmway/react-native-unity/ios/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/external/baselib/Include/C/Baselib_Debug.h:4:1
A type specifier is required for all declarations

